# Stop Visual Studio 2017 From Autogenerating Output Directory

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

So I have a solution with 70ish projects that I updated to use a Directory.build.props file to use a single bin folder to make our CI process cleaner. Works great and now everything is in 1 locaction

BUT the problem now is when I open Visual Studio 2017 it creates a bunch of extra project folders now that NEVER get used. Anyway to disable this? It's just confusing to people and clutters up everyone's dev repo.

Example:

%sourceroot%\bin\release\ (this is where all the projects get happily binplaced)

%sourceroot%\bin\project1Neverused\ (unwanted folders that just clutter my dev box up)

%sourceroot%\bin\project2neverUsed\

%sourceroot%\bin\project1Neverused\

%sourceroot%\bin\project2neverUsed\

Here's my Directory.build.props file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SolutionDir>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>`

Answer (score -1):

> Now open the sln file in Visual studio and if you look VS will have auto generated those folders even though you haven't built anything yet. I want that to be disabled because it's just generating junk folders that aren't used. Since we use a props file for msbuild to binplace we didn't update each project file from the default of "bin\debug"

Yes, Visual Studio will create those `bin/obj` folder by default when you create a new project/solution. It seems that there is no direct setting to prevent Visual Studio from generating these folders.

As a workaround, you can try to add a delete task in `Directory.build.props` file to delete the those folder:

```
  <Target Name="CleanFolder" AfterTargets="Build">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)bin" />
  </Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have the move setup. I'm taking about how Visual Studio will auto generate new folders for each project when you start it up for the first time.

Comment: If you need an example pull a clean Git repo for a C# project. Look at the project folders and notice there are no bin or obj or debug/release folders yet. Now open the sln file in Visual studio and if you look VS will have auto generated those folders even though you haven't built anything yet. I want that to be disabled because it's just generating junk folders that aren't used. Since we use a props file for msbuild to binplace we didn't update each project file from the default of "bin\debug" (since that's the whole point of the build.props is to avoid editing each project file).

Comment: @VictorLearned, Sorry misunderstanding your question. It seems that there is no direct setting to prevent Visual Studio from generating these folders, we could use a delete task in the Directory.build.props file to delete the those folder. Check the updated answer. Hope this helps.